# How can I change the 'little triangle color' in action bar NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

After I set `action bar` to `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

and then set an adapter for it.

The list show up as expected, but I need to change the 'little triangle' color of the list as the *default color* is very close to my *background color*.

Is it possible to do this, if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The little triangle you want to change is in the background of a `Spinner` widget in `ActionBar`. The background is a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). Items of the state list drawable are 9-patch drawables like this one (this particular one is the hdpi version for default state for Holo light theme):

[image]

To change the color of the triangle you have to change few sets of these 9-patch drawables - one drawable for each dpi and combination of states. You'll also need custom state list drawable to be as as the background of the `Spinner` widget.

To change the widget background you have to adjust the theme. If you are using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) (ABS) change `actionDropDownStyle` item and for native ActionBar change `android:actionDropDownStyle` item (even if you use ABS native ActionBar is used for devices running Android 4.0 and higher).

The theme should be something like:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="SomeParentStyle>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyActionBarSpinnerStyle</item><!-- if you use ABS -->
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyActionBarSpinnerStyle</item>
</style>
```

And `MyActionBarSpinnerStyle` should be something like:

```xml
<style name="MyActionBarSpinnerStyle" parent="@style/MyDropDownActionBarStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_custom_state_list_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Where instead of `MyDropDownActionBarStyle` there should be something like `Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar` if you use ABS or `Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar` if you target only native ActionBar.