# Change ActionBar spinner arrow color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

I styled my actionbar like so, which results in a normal spinner and not an action bar spinner (without the line on the bottom). But I do want it to be white and prefer to not user my own drawables for this and use the android's spinner style. (See below what the result is).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.OverFlow</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/AppTheme.actionBarDropDown</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/DropDownList</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dp</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">48dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.actionBarDropDown" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <!--<item name="android:background">@android:style/ab</item>-->
</style>
   <style name="DropDownList" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <!-- background of the list menu -->
    <item name="background">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <!-- dividers -->
    <item name="android:divider">@color/border_color</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dip</item>
    <!-- item selected -->
    <!--<item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>-->
</style>
```

[image: action bar problem]

as you see the line breaks my design of the title.
Does anyone know what I could change to use a normal actionbar spinner drawable?
I can't seem to find this anywhere on stack.

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=fff%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100

Comment: Check the link above. It will style actionbar to your needs

Comment: Not the part that I need. But thanks for reading my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868985/how-can-i-change-the-little-triangle-color-in-action-bar-navigation-mode-list. Found this interesting solution.

Comment: Oh I actually fixed it using your first link Just had to edit the images myself I guess the white one does not really exist.

Comment: True. I was about to suggest you the same way. But i hadn't actually implemented it myself so refrained from doing so.

Comment: If I use the image from the generator as the background, the drop down arrow is getting stretched and is not at right bottom as it is supposed to be. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you change the image file? seems like it's not working as a 9 patch image. (removed the black borders mayb?

Anyway I suggest opening a new question about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the comments of the question, it's based on resources which don't have a white arrow, it's grey and it's not for the actionbar. So the best option is to use the generator